# Горизонтальный скроллинг ссылок на мобильном экране

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

Есть блок с ссылками, по ширине он больше ширины экрана. Нужно чтобы эти ссылки прокручивались горизонтально (по проведению пальцев):

```css
@media(max-width: 350px) {
  .links {
    display: flex;
    height: 11px;
  }
  a {
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 11px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Главная</a>
  <a href="#">Nail-услуги</a>
  <a href="#">Hair-услуги</a>
  <a href="#">Косметология</a>
  <a href="#">Визаж</a>
  <a href="#">Эпиляция</a>
  <a href="#">Татуаж</a>
  <a href="#">Массаж</a>
  <a href="#">Ресницы</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос ? что именно у Вас не выходит ?

Answer (score 1):

По сути у Вас все должно работать и так, поскольку у дефолтные значения свойств [flex-row](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-row) и [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) равны "row" и "nowrap" соотвественно. Возможно стоит проверить [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) правило на соответствие размера, в примере ниже я симитировал его ограничение (в нем [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) вообще не требуется):

```css
.links {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.links > a {
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.links > a:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Главная</a>
  <a href="#">Nail-услуги</a>
  <a href="#">Hair-услуги</a>
  <a href="#">Косметология</a>
  <a href="#">Визаж</a>
  <a href="#">Эпиляция</a>
  <a href="#">Татуаж</a>
  <a href="#">Массаж</a>
  <a href="#">Ресницы</a>
</div>
```